# What is the easiest way to copy Chrome's login/passses into KeePass without creating duplicates?

Tags: google-chrome, keepass

Okey, here's the thing.

I have most of my login info in two places; one is in Keepass file and the other is in Chrome. Being a lazy sort of person, and since Chrome/Keepass integration never really started to work the way it should, a couple times a year I use the Nirsoft tool to get the Chrome login/passwords into a textual .csv file and then import it in Keepass. Creating lots of duplicates in the process which I then clean and so on.

In the meantime, all the new logins I accumulate just stay in Chrome.

As you might notice, this is not really the best way to do it. Is there a faster way to do this; copy logins from Chrome to Keepass without creating duplicates in Keepass, or has anyone perhaps found a way to get Keepass to work with Chrome under Win XP SP3? Keepass 1.0 or 2.0, doesn't make the difference as long as it works.

Comment: Either switch to Lastpass or use Firefox + KeeFox. Update: have you tried this: http://keepass.info/plugins.html#chromeipass ?

Comment: @billc.cn - Yes, that is what I've been describing.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will help - in KeePass (I'm using v2.2, but I believe older versions have it) - go to `Tools` --> `Database Tools` --> `Delete Duplicate Entries` - this should give you a clean slate to start from (Assuming this 1 year old question is still relevant)

**UPDATE**

I checked - it deletes exact duplicates. It needs `Title`, `User name`, `Password`, `URL` and `Notes` to be identical. 
I assume that if you have custom properties and auto-type definitions they will also have to be identical.

This might help you remove some duplicates - but probably not all.

Comment: Yes, it is still relevant (I just learned to ignore duplicates altogether, which is why my KeePass file now measures in megabytes). How does he "measure duplicates", do you know? Are they completely the same or does KeePass just check some cell values?

Comment: @Idigas: I have no idea :) - I assume it looks at users, urls, but not passwords

Comment: I'll play with it a bit. But not looking at passwords means that it'll just delete your new passwords and leave the old ones.